# Pass parameter to callback in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models: User and Favorite. In model Favorite:

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :user_id

  def self.add_favorite(options)
    create!(options)
  end

  def self.unfavorite(options)
    where(options).delete_all
  end
```

Now, I want to limit number of records saved to Favorite is 10. It mean that users are only liked 10 products. I researched google, someone said that I try to use callback and I think it's right way, but it raise 2 questions:
1. Can I use query in method for callback?
2. Callback can be pass argument?

It is sample code I think:

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :limit_records(user_id)
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :user_id

  def self.add_favorite(options)
    create!(options)
  end

  def self.unfavorite(options)
    where(options).delete_all
  end

  def limit_records(user_id)
    count = self.where(user_id: user_id).count
    self.where(used_id: user_id).last.delete if count > 10
  end
```

If user had 10 favorite, when they like any products, callback will be called after Favorite is created and will be delete if it's 11th record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :user_id
```

in your `Favorite` model and `limit_records` is an instance method on `Favorite`. So you have access to the user as `self.user_id` (or just `user_id` since `self` is implied) inside `limit_records` and there is no need for an argument:

```
after_create :limit_records

def limit_records
  # same as what you have now, `user_id` will be `self.user_id`
  # now that there is no `user_id` argument...
  count = self.where(user_id: user_id).count
  self.where(used_id: user_id).last.delete if count > 10
end
```

Comment: It worked. It's my code
```
def limit_record
    self.delete if Favorite.where(user_id: self.user_id).count > 10
  end
```
But it seem that transaction is used quite many. After creating new record, it have to call callback, run if condition, if it's false, it have to destroy it. It mean:
create -> callback -> destroy.
So that, I want to validate it right at creation step. So I want to use before_create. It's my code
```
return false if Favorite.where(user_id: self.user_id).count >= 10
```
But it doesn't work. Please help me this case.

Comment: Hard to read your comment but perhaps you're looking for something like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+validate+association+count